# Oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch except that it matches exactly

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, sandbox

So I created a new Connected App in Salesforce - in a sandbox environment. In the app's settings I enabled OAuth with Full access and set the Callback URI to `https://test.mydomain.com/tools/account_history.php`

This was about a week ago, so I know that the Callback URI has had *plenty* of time to fully propagate. However, if I try loading the auth URL it returns this error every time:

`error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration`

These are the auth URLs I have been trying:

https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_URI=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.mydomain.com%2Ftools%2Faccount_history.php

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_URI=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.mydomain.com%2Ftools%2Faccount_history.php

https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_URI=https://test.mydomain.com/tools/account_history.php

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_URI=https://test.mydomain.com/tools/account_history.php

Is there perhaps an entirely different auth URL to use for sandboxed environments? The error seems misleading since the URI I'm sending in my auth request does *precisely* match my configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your sandbox has My Domain enabled, replace test.salesforce.com with your domain and try again.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know about My Domain! It was enabled although `Prevent login from https://test.salesforce.com` was unchecked. At any rate, I just tried using the My Domain setting `https://mydomain--Full.cs47.my.salesforce.com` but receive the same result. I thought for sure this was the issue. I'll keep trying.

Comment: which OAuth flow are you trying to use? I noticed you are not passing the client secret.

Comment: Authorization Code Grant: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1

Comment: Got it! So I had been using an example URL structure from one of the countless outdated examples floating out there on the web. The particular example I had borrowed from set the URL as `&redirect_URI=` but apparently this is case sensitive and needs to be `&redirect_uri=` . Thanks so much for your help, not using the My Domain setting was also a big part of the problem!

Comment: I had no idea urls could be case sensitive! Great find!

Comment: URLs are not case sensitive. Only parameters could be case sensitive if not handled properly while fetching them - either parameter name or value - which looks like it with this particular case