# error=redirect_uri_mismatch Oauth2

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, refresh-token, accesstoken

I having trouble to create the Refresh Token.

I want to give it to a third party, So it can use it to get an access token and send us data using an exposing web service that I created.

I tried to do the following steps :

1. I created a Connected App.
2. I gave the right OAuth Scopes.
3. Defined a Callback URL.
4. Open a web browser with the follwoing URL :

> https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9llQY5kM.....
>       &​redirect_uri=https://mySandbox.cs108.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize

5. Got the mismatch Error :

> error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration

The Url that gave the mismatch is :

> https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9llQY5kM9....&?redirect_uri=https://mySandbox.cs108.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize

Inside my connected App - the Callback URL is exactly the same as the requested URI + I waited 24 hours and not just 10 min for the connected App to be available.

[image]

I also tried to add the scope param as : `scope=refresh_token` , but it give me the same error.

I also tried to do it from my domain since it enabled - but same response.
The prevent "test.salesforce" is not checked anyway.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279466/oauth2-redirect-uri-mismatch-except-that-it-matches-exactly - is My Domain enabled?

Comment: Ayub thanks for responding. I just checked it and updated my answer - spoiler - same response - unfortunately

Comment: I'm wondering if you have enabled then why still cs108 is in url ... please recheck your url?

Comment: Hi Ayub,
I updated the Pic of the My domain.. It has cs108 there also...